# \[Ext.createByAlias\] Unrecognized alias: data.field.text when migrating a Ext4 to Ext5 codebase

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am migrating a large codebase (that I didn't write) from Ext JS 4 to Ext JS 5. While creating a new model definition, I noticed that the following code:

```
Ext.define('host', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'ip',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'hostname',
        type: 'text'
    }]
});
```

works with Ext js 4 but fails on Ext 5 with the message:

```
Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: data.field.text
```

Obviously the solution here is to change the type: 'text' to type: 'string'
However I noticed that in the Ext js 4 [availables types](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Types), 'text' was not even here. How did this possibly work ?

Comment: type: 'text' is causing that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Ext.data.Field's constructor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-method-constructor) (Ext JS 4), it determined the type by:

```
if (me.type) {
    if (Ext.isString(me.type)) {
        me.type = types[me.type.toUpperCase()] || types.AUTO;
    }
} else {
    me.type = types.AUTO;
}
```

It would not find 'text', so it would set it to 'AUTO'.

Since you were setting it to type 'text', I'm assuming its values were alphanumeric, so it would secretly use 'string' as its type.

In ExtJS 5, they've added much better error messages to help keep you on track, so that is why you are now seeing that error.

Comment: So if I get it right, I am getting this message in Ext JS 5, because the framework is now more stringent about the rightness of the data type ?

Comment: That's my impression as well. Rather than silently fix any problems by converting your code (possibly causing it to do something unexpected), it now throws a descriptive error message forcing you to fix the issue.